# Why does “Fresnel'sche” have an apostrophe and “Gaußsche” doesn't?

Tags: grammar

In German physics literature, I often see adjectives like “Gaußsche” and “Fresnel'sche”. I know what they mean in the context, that Gauß (or Fresnel) invented something or that it is named after them. But why does one have an apostrophe in it, and the other does not? What does that mean (i. e. what am I leaving out?) and which is the right way?

Comment: I found [this](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Auskunft/Archiv/2009#.28M.2Fm.3F.29ustermann.28.E2.80.99.29sche_Adjektivierung).

Comment: @K.Stm. Then summarize it in an answer ;)

Comment: Where in the actual question text is a reference to "Where does “Gaußsche” and “Fresnel'sche” come from"? The question seems more to deal with "which is correct", as far as I can tell.

Comment: One standard object in mathematics and physics is the _Fresnelsche Wellenfläche_. You can check for publications of the author H Knörrer, for instance. By the way, I have never met a mathematician who writes the terms referred to with a small initial letter. And an apostrophe is not needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ich hoffe, es ist in Ordnung, wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte.

**Korrekt: Ohne Apostroph, kleingeschrieben**

Vorzuziehen ist die Version ohne Apostroph. Dann entsteht aber ein Adjektiv, und das ist kleinzuschreiben:

> Die gaußsche Glockenkurve
>   Die loschmidtsche Zahl
>   Das ohmsche Gesetz
>   Die kleinsche Flasche

**Korrekte Alternative: Mit Apostroph, großgeschrieben**

Alternativ dazu ist auch die Version mit Apostroph erlaubt, dann bleiben die Namen Hauptwörter und sind daher auch großzuschreiben:

> Die Gauß'sche Glockenkurve
>   Die Loschmidt'sche Zahl
>   Das Ohm'sche Gesetz
>   Die Klein'sche Flasche

**Auch in Ordnung: Ohne Apostroph, großgeschrieben**

Gelegentlich findet man auch die Version ohne Apostroph, allerdings großgeschrieben. Das wäre eigentlich falsch, aber "Gaußsche Glockenkurve" ist ein mehrteiliger Eigenname (so wie "Zweiter Weltkrieg", "Roter Platz" usw.), und daher darf auch das darin enthaltene Adjektiv großgeschrieben werden.

> Die Gaußsche Glockenkurve
>   Die Loschmidtsche Zahl
>   Das Ohmsche Gesetz
>   Die Kleinsche Flasche

Alle drei Versionen bedeuten dasselbe. Wie immer gilt, wenn man Wahlmöglichkeiten hat: Wenn man sich innerhalb eines Textes mal für eine Variante entschieden hat, sollte man in diesem Text auch bei dieser Wahl bleiben.

Comment: Um genau zu sein, groß ohne Apostroph war die einzig korrekte Schreibung vor der Rechtschreibreform. Nach der Rechtschreibreform sind die anderen beiden Versionen korrekt.

Comment: Nicely analyzed, Hubert, and as a math/physics guy I liked your examples.

Comment: Zur Diskussion siehe auch dieses Video: http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/zeichensetzung/apostroph.php , welches m.E. sehr zu Recht die Frage aufwirft, wieso der Apostroph bei Kleinschreibung verschwinden darf, bzw. umgekehrt, wieso er bei Großschreibung stehen sollte. Der Macher bestreitet, dass es stehen sollte und bringt einleuchtende Argumente.

Comment: Die dritte Variante (ohne Apostroph, groß) ist allerdings nur korrekt in Fällen, in denen auch viele andere Wörter groß geschrieben werden (Adverbien, Verben usw.). Insofern ist es keine Regel für die Schreibung von aus Personennamen abgeleiteten Adjektive, denn aus diesem Fall kann man keineswegs schließen, dass man die apostrophlose Form immer groß schreiben darf..