# "Von neumannsche Ordinalzahlen" oder "von Neumann'sche Ordinalzahlen"?

Tags: adjective, spelling, person-names, mathematics, apostrophe

Sofern ich weiß sind sowohl *grimmsche Märchen* und *Grimm'sche Märchen* korrekt.
Was passiert wenn das Adjektiv von einem mehrteiligen Namen kommt, zum Beispiel [**von** Neumann](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann).

Welche Formen sind korrekt oder zu bevorzugen?

- *von neumannsche Ordinalzahlen*
- *neumannsche Ordinalzahlen*
- *von Neumann'sche Ordinalzahlen*
- *Neumann'sche Ordinalzahlen*

Comment: Wenn Ihr die erste Inkarnation dieser Frage (oder irgendwas das damit zusammenhängt) diskutieren möchtet, tut dies bitte [im Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/deutschsprachiger-raum).

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/q/5316/1487

Answer (score 7):

§49 der Rechtschreibregeln:

> Bei Ableitungen von mehreren Eigennamen, von Titeln und Eigennamen oder von einem mehrteiligen Eigennamen setzt man einen Bindestrich.

dort werden die Beispiele

1. > die kant-laplacesche Theorie (Kant und Laplace),
2. > der de-costersche Roman (de Coster),
3. > die gräflich-rienecksche Güterverwaltung (Graf Rieneck)
4. > die Kant-Laplace’sche Theorie (Kant und Laplace),
5. > der de-Coster’sche Roman (de Coster),
6. > die Gräflich-Rieneck’sche Güterverwaltung (Graf Rieneck)

aufgeführt. Die Beispiele (2) und (5) lassen sich direkt auf deines übertragen.

Folglich sind nur

- ***von-neumannsche Ordnungszahlen*** und
- ***von-Neumann'sche Ordnungszahlen***

vollkommen richtig. Zwischen diesen beiden richtigen Schreibweisen sehe ich keine Präferenz. Die andern sind natürlich falsch und daher "nicht zu bevorzugen" ;) .

Aus purer Verlegenheit das "von" wegzulassen wie in manchen deiner Beispiele kommt wohl überhaupt nicht in Frage - der Mann heißt nunmal "von Neumann" und nicht anders.

Die Groß- und Kleinschreibung ergibt sich aus Regel 62:

> *Kleingeschrieben werden adjektivische Ableitungen von Eigennamen auf -(i)sch, außer wenn die Grundform eines Personennamens durch einen Apostroph verdeutlicht wird, ferner alle adjektivischen Ableitungen mit anderen Suffixen.*

Comment: Andererseits ist der Adel abgeschafft. :)

Comment: @userunknown Ich glaube nicht, dass sich deshalb die Namen geändert haben...

Comment: @tofro Das ist absolut korrekt!

Comment: Es sagt wohl niemand "die von-Goethe'sche Dichtung".

Comment: @fdb Goethe ist was anderes - der hieß ja nicht immer "von".

Comment: *»Aus purer Verlegenheit das "von" wegzulassen ... kommt wohl überhaupt nicht in Frage«* Warum habe ich dann bisher noch nie den Ausdruck *»van-Beethovens 9. Symphonie«* gehört oder gelesen? Hingegen begegnet mir seht oft *»Beethovens 9. Symphonie«*. Auch über *»von-Goethes Faust«* liest man recht wenig, über *»Goethes Faust«* wird hingegen viel und oft geschrieben und geredet. Auch *»von-Habsburgische Erblande«* sind mir noch nie untergekommen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das sind alles Namen, die zum selbstständigen Begriff geworden sind (auch Goethe gehört dazu) - Man sagt ja auch "Goethes Faust" ohne "von". Bei "von Neumann" ist das wohl noch nicht so. In meiner Praxis geht es gar nicht, zu zitieren und den Namen des Verfassers nicht richtig zu nennnen. Da der Frager mit einem mathematischen Kontext fragt, geht's da wohl auch nicht.

Comment: @tofro Sehr gute Antwort! Aber: "Goethe ist was anderes" triftt nicht zu. John von Neumann war gebürtiger Ungar (geb. 1903 als *János Lajos Neumann*). Sein Vater wurde 1913 geadelt und erhielt dabei den Namen *Margittai Neumann* (auf Deutsch *Neumann von Margitta*). Den Namen *Johann von Neumann* bzw. *John von Neumann* hat er selbst in seinen Publikationen verwendet.

Comment: @PaulFrost "Goethe ist was anderes" - ich wollte das nicht näher ausführen, aber Goethe hat den Faust geschrieben (1772), *bevor* er in den Adelsstand erhoben wurde (1782). Daher ist "Goethes Faust" sachlich vollkommen richtig.